# Racket, access structure fields in function

Tags: racket, structure

I have a fold function that I want to use on a number of different structures, each structure with arbitrarily named fields.  Thus, I need to tell the fold function what kind of structure was passed to it, and which field to access.  I need something like this:

```
(define-struct test (element))
(define test_struct (make-test 0))

(define (getfield elementname structure)
  ((typeof structure)-elementname structure))

(getfield element test_struct)
```

The last line is then equivalent to:

```
(test-element test_struct)
```

Of course none of the above is correct syntax, but it should display what I'm going for.  Based on some other questions here on stackoverflow, it seems the answer has something to do with `syntax` but I have no idea exactly how that works.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## What won't work

Although you can [introspect the struct type at **run** time](http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/inspectors.html), I don't see how you could use that in a macro at **compile** time. Because at compile time you don't have anything to give `object-name` except a piece of syntax -- not a live struct object with a type:

```
(require (for-syntax racket/syntax))
(define-syntax (get-field stx)
  (syntax-case stx ()
    [(_ field-name s)
     (with-syntax ([id (format-id stx
                                  "~a-~a"
                                  (object-name #'s) ; um, yeah, this won't work
                                  #'field-name)])
       #'(id s))]))
```

## What would work instead?

1. You could have your `fold`-ish function accept an additional argument -- which is the field accessor function. In your example, it would be the `test-element` function that accesses the `element` field of a `test` struct type.

   This is similar to how Racket's `sort` has an optional `#:key extract-key` argument, which is a function to apply to each item to get the value to be used for sorting. For example if you were sorting a list of `test` `struct`s, you could pass the `test-element` accessor function.

   --OR--
2. You could use a dictionary instead of a struct. The equivalent of what you had above, but using a `hasheq`:

   ```
   (define test (hasheq 'element 0))
   (hash-ref test 'element)  ; => 0
   ```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer.  I ended up doing option number 1.  It's kind of hack-y but hey, sometimes that's just what's needed!

Comment: @NickO I should have mentioned there's a precedent for this in Racket: The optional `#:key extract-key` argument to `sort` <docs.racket-lang.org/reference/pairs.html#(def._((lib._racket%2Fprivate%2Flist..rkt)._sort))>. That is a function to apply to the item to get the "interesting" value.